# How to run .riv animation in splash screen using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, splash-screen, rive

Iam unable to run .riv animation in splash screen. Please help me to do so. I ran it simply, it is working but it's not working in splash screen.
Help me with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You cant add rive to default launch screens(you can edit them though, take a look at [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen)). But you can create a separate flutter page and use that as your first page. something like this:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SplashPage(), // your rive animation goes here
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rive lib for flutter:

https://pub.dev/packages/rive_splash_screen